# How to use the input off a form from a jsp page as parameters for a method from a java class

Tags: html, spring, jsp

What i want to do is create a login page with jsp. I have never used jsp before so i did some research on it, and learned how to use java beans en java code mixed with html. So i can send the inputs from the login jsp to another jsp page and retrieve the data with `request.getParameter()`, but my question is how can i call a method from the java bean/class.

The method checks if the login data is legit or not. I want to call the method in the same jsp page as the login form, is that possible?

```
<%@<jsp:useBean id="service" class="FavoriteService" scope="session"/>
" %>
```

This is how i declared/initialised my class in the login jsp page

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic code inside a servlet, and map it to `/login` URL for example (via `web.xml`). Before forwarding the request from the servlet to the JSP file (`request.getRequestDispatcher("/login").forward(request, response)`), you can pass the result of the logic code via `request.setAttribute("SomeKey", someResult)` method. Inside the JSP file, you can access the request attribute via EL expression (`${requestScope.SomeKey}`).